# How to make an app available to install on Android for Work

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-for-work, mobileiron

**Problem**

I have been developing a Xamarin.Forms App for the Android platform. The App is intended to be released on the Google Play Store, but for testing purposes I need to deploy a beta version through our MobileIron Internal App Store towards devices which have an Android For Work profile enabled. However, the app cannot be installed on these devices.

**Specifications**

- The app has been developed with Xamarin.Forms
- The app has minimum Android Version 4.4 (API Level 19)
- The app has target Android Version 8.1 (API Level 27)
- The app is able to be installed through MS App Center on other devices which do not hold this Android For Work profile which is managed by MobileIron.
- The app has been uploaded through our MobileIron Internal App Store without being wrapped through the MobileIron Developer Portal.
- The app has been uploaded through our MobileIron Internal App Store while being wrapped through the MobileIron Developer Portal.

**Message**

The message when selecting the App in the MobileIron Internal Store is in Dutch and says: "Deze app is niet beschikbaar voor apparaten met Android For Work." which roughly translates to: "This app is not available for devices using Android For Work" while the install button is disabled (greyed out).

I have not had a lot of experience with MobileIron or devices which hold an Android For Work profile, so any suggestion could help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the minimum SDK value to something higher than level 21?

"Android 5.0 (API level 21) allows organizations to set up work profiles".
https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles.html

Comment: Rodrigo, thanks for the comment. Have provided an Android 6.0 (API level 23) and 64-bit architecture (read those recommendations on some site about Android For Work) APK to the team. Will let you know when I know.

Comment: Have you followed the work here?http://mi.extendedhelp.mobileiron.com/39/all/en/desktop/How_to_Set_Up_Android_For_Work.htm

Comment: Unfortunately upgrading the API level an architecture did not work. I have provided some suggestions from your link to the team Abby, thanks. Will let you know. Also letting them look into white- and blacklisting for apps...